# C/C++ Macro expansion : from two to four parameters

Tags: c++, macros

I'm trying to convert a two parameter macro into a four parameter one. From
the definition of `LIST` which I can't change, I'd like to call `ALL`, 
providing the two extra parameters.

```
#define LIST(x) \
   x(p1, p2)    \
   x(p3, p4)    \
   x(...

#define ALL(A, B, C, D) .../... do stuff with A, B, C and D
```

Here's what I tried so far:

```
#define RIGHT(C, D) C, D)
#define LEFT(A, B) (A, B, RIGHT
```

But when I'm testing it (`gcc -E text.cpp`) with `LIST( ALL LEFT (q1, q2) )` I 
get the following error:

> error: unterminated argument list invoking macro "ALL"

Taking a closer look at it, this is why:

1. `LIST` is substituted which give for the first line 
   `ALL LEFT (q1, q2)(p1, p2)`
2. `LEFT`is substituted to `ALL (q1, q2, RIGHT(p1, p2)`
3. The preprocessor tries to expand `ALL`, but doesn't find the closing
   parenthesis, there's the error...

How can I do otherwise?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

To be more precise, with the given input:

```
#define LIST(x) \
   x("p1", "p2")    \
   x("p3", "p4")    \
   x("p5", "p6")
#define ALL(A, B, C, D) {A, B, C, D}
```

I want to find a way to get, as a result:

```
{"q1", "q2", "p1", "p2"}
{"q1", "q2", "p3", "p4"}
{"q1", "q2", "p5", "p6"}
```

Comment: What is the exact question. What is the input and what is the expected outcome you want ?

Comment: Is that exactly how `LIST` is defined? Namely, how are the `x`s separated from each other?

Comment: How do you expect to get the q's when they are not passed into the macro?

Comment: May I ask how you are using that output? Do you perhaps want to put comma's in between so you can use it to initialize a 2d array of strings?

Comment: @gregseth:
As for preprocessor macro, probably you can see their definition
(that is, they aren't converted to binary object file).
So if you copy-and-paste the definition of `LIST` macro,
you can modify it as you wish, I think.
Isn't this true in your case?

Comment: @dribeas That's precisely my question, what macro should I define (with the q's as input) to get the output I want.

Comment: @Shahbaz That's just to simplify the example. The _real_ output if far more complicated than that.

Comment: @Ise THe point is to define the values of LIST only once. After a copy-paste any change would have to be made twice.

Comment: @gregseth: Ah, I see.
Then _Shahbaz_'s comment to the answer seems the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

I see two anwers to this:

1) Pass in the name of a helper macro when using LIST:

```
#define to_all(c, d) ALL("q1", "q2", c, d)
LIST(to_all)
```

2) Let LIST expand to helper macros, which is expected to exist when used (this is a variant of something named x-macros). This, however, would require you to redefine list:

```
// Somewhere "central"
#define LIST() \
   LIST_HELPER("p1", "p2")    \
   LIST_HELPER("p3", "p4")    \
   LIST_HELPER("p5", "p6")
#define ALL(A, B, C, D) {A, B, C, D}

// When used:
#define LIST_HELPER(c, d) ALL("q1", "q2", c, d)
LIST()
#undef LIST_HELPER
```

Comment: The first method is the correct answer. If you have read the OPs question, he cannot alter the definition of LIST

Comment: Thanks. For a direct call to `LIST(to_all)` it's perfect, but what if I need to pass `"q1"` and `"q2"`as 'variables'.

Comment: It depends on the context. You can always define a special `to_all` macro for each distinct situation, then you can include you variables in the definition.

Comment: @gregseth, to pass "q1", "q2" as argument, you can do it like this (similar to the second method). In `to_all` expand to `ALL(PARAMETERS, c, d)` and when you use `LIST` you write: `#define PARAMETER "q1", "q2"` (next line) `LIST(to_all)` (next line) `undef PARAMETER`. I will edit this answer to show that if Lindydancer accepts it

Comment: By the way @Lindydancer, I also dance lindy hop!

Comment: @Shahbaz The thing is the call to `LIST(...)` is made in another define where the q's are some of the parameters.

Comment: @gregseth, well just define `PARAMETER` outside where _that_ macro is called. If inside that macro, the q's need to change, I need to think about it a bit more.

Comment: Yes, inside that macro, the q's need to change.

Comment: I think that you will have to provide an example of what you need to do, it's not clear how the q:s will change.

Comment: Let's say I have another define like that : `#define ANOTHER(x,y) LIST(/* what do I put here */)` where  `x` and `y` are the q's.